# How to configure pgadmin4 (PostgreSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I finished installation `postgresql-10.5` and ran `pgadmin4` (that came installed with `postgresql`) I get a configuration error that says:

```
An error occurred initializing the application server:
Failed to launch application server, server thread existing
```

It then asks me to input a python path and an application path.

Can anybody help me and and advise what to do to run pgadmin4. I tried find problem solution, but nothing helped me(